Sharing Screen Capture Disconnects MultipeerConnectivity over WebRTC Across iOS Devices
I'm building a prototype app that showcases the functionality on iOS to capture a device's screen, connect to another device, and then video stream this (as high res and low latency) over a local WiFi network. The chosen lib I'm implementing this with is WebRTC (open to other suggestions).
The Issue:
I load the app onto 2 devices, I broadcast the screen of one device, it appears from the logs to connect to the other device I have set to receive, but after that they appear to drop connection with "[GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [xxxxxxxx] on channel [x]" on 5 channel.
I've included the full code you can run in Xcode below along with a console from the connecting device during the last build and dropped connection.
I'm at a frustrating DEAD END.
WebRTCManager.swift
import Foundation
import WebRTC
import ReplayKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class WebRTCManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection?
    @Published var localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
    @Published var remoteVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
    private var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory?
    private var videoSource: RTCVideoSource?
    private var videoCapturer: RTCVideoCapturer?
    
    private var peerID: MCPeerID
    private var session: MCSession
    private var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser?
    private var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser?
    
    @Published var connectedPeers: [MCPeerID] = []
    @Published var localSDP: String = ""
    @Published var localICECandidates: [String] = []
    
    @Published var isBroadcasting: Bool = false
    @Published var remoteTrackAdded: Bool = false
    
    private var isConnected = false

    override init() {
        RTCInitializeSSL()
        peerConnectionFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory()
        
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .none)
        
        super.init()
        
        session.delegate = self
    }
    
    func startBroadcasting() {
        isBroadcasting = true
        advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "screen-share")
        advertiser?.delegate = self
        advertiser?.startAdvertisingPeer()
        
        setupPeerConnection()
        setupVideoSource()
        startScreenCapture()
    }

    func startReceiving() {
        browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerID, serviceType: "screen-share")
        browser?.delegate = self
        browser?.startBrowsingForPeers()
        
        setupPeerConnection()
    }
    
    private func setupPeerConnection() {
        let configuration = RTCConfiguration()
        configuration.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"])]
        configuration.sdpSemantics = .unifiedPlan
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: nil)
        peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory?.peerConnection(with: configuration, constraints: constraints, delegate: self)
        
        // Ensure peer connection state is checked before proceeding
        guard let peerConnection = peerConnection else {
            print("Failed to create peer connection")
            return
        }
        
        peerConnection.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func setupVideoSource() {
        videoSource = peerConnectionFactory?.videoSource()
        
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        videoCapturer = RTCFileVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource!)
        #else
        videoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource!)
        #endif
        
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory?.videoTrack(with: videoSource!, trackId: "video0")
        
        if let localVideoTrack = localVideoTrack {
            peerConnection?.add(localVideoTrack, streamIds: ["stream0"])
            print("Local video track added to peer connection")
        } else {
            print("Failed to create local video track")
        }
    }
    
    private func startScreenCapture() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
        recorder.startCapture { [weak self] (sampleBuffer, type, error) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error starting screen capture: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            if type == .video {
                self.processSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, with: type)
            }
        } completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in screen capture completion: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Screen capture started successfully")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        switch sampleBufferType {
        case .video:
            guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
            
            let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
            let videoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(buffer: RTCCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer),
                                           rotation: ._0,
                                           timeStampNs: Int64(timestamp))
            
            self.videoSource?.capturer(self.videoCapturer!, didCapture: videoFrame)
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func stopBroadcasting() {
        isBroadcasting = false
        advertiser?.stopAdvertisingPeer()
        advertiser = nil
        stopScreenCapture()
        closePeerConnection()
    }

    func stopReceiving() {
        browser?.stopBrowsingForPeers()
        browser = nil
        closePeerConnection()
    }
    
    private func stopScreenCapture() {
        RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture { [weak self] error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error stopping screen capture: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Screen capture stopped successfully")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.localVideoTrack = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func closePeerConnection() {
        guard let peerConnection = peerConnection else { return }
        
        if isConnected {
            // Properly handle disconnection if connected
            peerConnection.close()
        }
        self.peerConnection = nil
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.remoteVideoTrack = nil
            self.localSDP = ""
            self.localICECandidates.removeAll()
        }
        print("Peer connection closed")
    }
    
    private func createOffer() {
        print("Creating offer")
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [
            "OfferToReceiveVideo": "true",
            "OfferToReceiveAudio": "false"
        ], optionalConstraints: nil)
        peerConnection?.offer(for: constraints) { [weak self] sdp, error in
            guard let self = self, let sdp = sdp else {
                print("Failed to create offer: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
                return
            }
            self.peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(sdp) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error setting local description: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Local description (offer) set successfully")
                    self.sendSDP(sdp)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func createAnswer() {
        print("Creating answer")
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [
            "OfferToReceiveVideo": "true",
            "OfferToReceiveAudio": "false"
        ], optionalConstraints: nil)
        peerConnection?.answer(for: constraints) { [weak self] sdp, error in
            guard let self = self, let sdp = sdp else {
                print("Failed to create answer: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
                return
            }
            self.peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(sdp) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error setting local description: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Local description (answer) set successfully")
                    self.sendSDP(sdp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setRemoteDescription(_ sdp: RTCSessionDescription) {
        peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(sdp) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error setting remote description: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Remote description set successfully")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addIceCandidate(_ candidate: RTCIceCandidate) {
        guard let peerConnection = peerConnection, isConnected else {
            print("Cannot add ICE candidate, peer connection is not connected")
            return
        }
        peerConnection.add(candidate)
        print("ICE candidate added")
    }
    
    private func sendSDP(_ sdp: RTCSessionDescription) {
        let dict: [String: Any] = ["type": sdp.type.rawValue, "sdp": sdp.sdp]
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) {
            do {
                try session.send(data, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
                print("SDP sent to peers")
            } catch {
                print("Failed to send SDP: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension WebRTCManager: MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {

    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.connectedPeers = session.connectedPeers
            switch state {
            case .connected:
                print("Peer connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
                self.browser?.stopBrowsingForPeers()
                self.advertiser?.stopAdvertisingPeer()
                self.isConnected = true  // Set isConnected to true here
                if self.isBroadcasting {
                    self.createOffer()
                }
            case .connecting:
                print("Peer connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
            case .notConnected:
                print("Peer not connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
                self.isConnected = false
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown state: \(peerID.displayName)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        if let typeInt = dict?["type"] as? Int, let sdp = dict?["sdp"] as? String,
           let type = RTCSdpType(rawValue: typeInt) {
            let rtcSdp = RTCSessionDescription(type: type, sdp: sdp)
            
            self.peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(rtcSdp) { [weak self] error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error setting remote description: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Remote description set successfully")
                    if type == .offer {
                        self?.createAnswer()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if let sdp = dict?["candidate"] as? String,
                  let sdpMid = dict?["sdpMid"] as? String,
                  let sdpMLineIndexString = dict?["sdpMLineIndex"] as? String,
                  let sdpMLineIndex = Int32(sdpMLineIndexString) {
            let candidate = RTCIceCandidate(sdp: sdp, sdpMLineIndex: sdpMLineIndex, sdpMid: sdpMid)
            self.peerConnection?.add(candidate)
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}
    
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {}
    
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {}
    
    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void) {
        invitationHandler(true, session)
    }
    
    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 30)
    }
    
    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}
}

extension WebRTCManager: RTCPeerConnectionDelegate {
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange stateChanged: RTCSignalingState) {
        print("Signaling state changed: \(stateChanged.rawValue)")
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didAdd stream: RTCMediaStream) {
        print("Stream added with ID: \(stream.streamId)")
        if let videoTrack = stream.videoTracks.first {
            print("Video track added: \(videoTrack.trackId)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.remoteVideoTrack = videoTrack
                self.remoteTrackAdded = true
                self.objectWillChange.send()
                print("Remote video track set")
            }
        } else {
            print("No video tracks in the stream")
        }
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didRemove stream: RTCMediaStream) {
        print("Stream removed")
    }
    
    func peerConnectionShouldNegotiate(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection) {
        print("Negotiation needed")
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceConnectionState) {
        print("ICE connection state changed: \(newState.rawValue)")
        switch newState {
        case .checking, .connected, .completed:
            print("ICE connected")
            self.isConnected = true
        case .failed, .disconnected, .closed:
            print("ICE connection failed or closed")
            self.isConnected = false
            // Handle reconnection or cleanup if necessary
        case .new:
            print("New ICE connection")
        case .count:
            print("ICE count")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown ICE state")
        }
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceGatheringState) {
        print("ICE gathering state changed: \(newState.rawValue)")
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didGenerate candidate: RTCIceCandidate) {
         print("ICE candidate generated: \(candidate.sdp)")
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.localICECandidates.append(candidate.sdp)
         }
         
         // Always send ICE candidates
         let dict: [String: Any] = ["candidate": candidate.sdp, "sdpMid": candidate.sdpMid ?? "", "sdpMLineIndex": candidate.sdpMLineIndex]
         if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) {
             do {
                 try session.send(data, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
                 print("ICE candidate sent to peers")
             } catch {
                 print("Failed to send ICE candidate: \(error)")
             }
         }
     }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didRemove candidates: [RTCIceCandidate]) {
        print("Removed ICE candidates")
    }
    
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didOpen dataChannel: RTCDataChannel) {
        print("Data channel opened")
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let remoteVideoTrackAdded = Notification.Name("remoteVideoTrackAdded")
}

RTCVideoView.swift
import SwiftUI
import WebRTC

struct RTCVideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webRTCManager: WebRTCManager
    var isLocal: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCMTLVideoView {
        let videoView = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: .zero)
        videoView.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        updateVideoTrack(videoView)
        return videoView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: RTCMTLVideoView, context: Context) {
        updateVideoTrack(uiView)
    }

    private func updateVideoTrack(_ uiView: RTCMTLVideoView) {
        if isLocal {
            if let localVideoTrack = webRTCManager.localVideoTrack {
                localVideoTrack.add(uiView)
                print("Local video track added to view")
            } else {
                print("Local video track is nil")
            }
        } else {
            if let remoteVideoTrack = webRTCManager.remoteVideoTrack {
                remoteVideoTrack.add(uiView)
                print("Remote video track added to view")
            } else {
                print("Remote video track is nil")
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: RTCVideoView

        init(_ parent: RTCVideoView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(remoteVideoTrackAdded), name: .remoteVideoTrackAdded, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func remoteVideoTrackAdded() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.webRTCManager.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
}


ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI
import WebRTC
import MultipeerConnectivity
import ReplayKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var webRTCManager = WebRTCManager()
    @State private var isBroadcasting = false
    @State private var isReceiving = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isBroadcasting {
                Text("Broadcasting")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                // Local video preview
                RTCVideoView(webRTCManager: webRTCManager, isLocal: true)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3)) // Add a semi-transparent gray background
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                Button("Stop Broadcasting") {
                    webRTCManager.stopBroadcasting()
                    isBroadcasting = false
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

                // ... (existing code for SDP and ICE candidates)
            } else if isReceiving {
                Text("Receiving")
                    .font(.headline)
                RTCVideoView(webRTCManager: webRTCManager, isLocal: false)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3)) // Add a semi-transparent gray background
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                Button("Stop Receiving") {
                    webRTCManager.stopReceiving()
                    isReceiving = false
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            } else {
                Button("Start Broadcasting") {
                    webRTCManager.startBroadcasting()
                    isBroadcasting = true
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

                Button("Start Receiving") {
                    webRTCManager.startReceiving()
                    isReceiving = true
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }

            Text("Connected Peers: \(webRTCManager.connectedPeers.count)")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()

            if !webRTCManager.connectedPeers.isEmpty {
                Text("Connected to:")
                ForEach(webRTCManager.connectedPeers, id: \.self) { peer in
                    Text(peer.displayName)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


Console of connecting device:
2024-07-08 22:04:22.574897+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914162] Metal API Validation Enabled
Remote video track is nil
Remote video track is nil
2024-07-08 22:04:56.058516+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914299] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2024-07-08 22:04:56.058657+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914299] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
Peer connecting: iPhone
Remote video track is nil
Peer connected: iPhone
Remote video track is nil
Signaling state changed: 3
Stream added with ID: stream0
Video track added: video0
Remote description set successfully
Creating answer
Remote video track set
Remote video track added to view
Signaling state changed: 0
Local description (answer) set successfully
SDP sent to peers
ICE gathering state changed: 1
ICE candidate generated: candidate:617392483 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.112 63716 typ host generation 0 ufrag umCW network-id 1 network-cost 10
ICE candidate sent to peers
ICE candidate generated: candidate:3503244297 1 udp 2122194687 169.254.104.95 64683 typ host generation 0 ufrag umCW network-id 2 network-cost 10
ICE candidate sent to peers
Remote video track added to view
Remote video track added to view
ICE candidate generated: candidate:1783584147 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.112 51096 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag umCW network-id 1 network-cost 10
ICE candidate sent to peers
ICE candidate generated: candidate:2655828217 1 tcp 1518214911 169.254.104.95 51097 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag umCW network-id 2 network-cost 10
ICE candidate sent to peers
Remote video track added to view
ICE candidate generated: candidate:2776936407 1 udp 1686052607 2.28.217.67 63716 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.112 rport 63716 generation 0 ufrag umCW network-id 1 network-cost 10
ICE candidate sent to peers
Remote video track added to view
Remote video track added to view
2024-07-08 22:05:06.151870+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [0].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.155864+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [1].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.158066+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [2].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.159428+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [3].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.160762+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [4].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.161831+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [5].
2024-07-08 22:05:06.162682+0100 ScreenShare[2745:914169] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [780785AF] on channel [6].
ICE gathering state changed: 2

I have fiddled with the projects settings and added anything I've found could be causing the issue — due to its absence from the Info.plist — and added it in:
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>_screen-share._tcp</string>
        <string>_screen-share._udp</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>nearby-interaction</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>voip</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

